# Typecasting multiple time versus having single pointer

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a doubt about which is better from performance point of view.

I have a variable of type aViewController and it contains an object of bViewController.
so every time i need to call a method on bViewController  I call it like (bViewController *)aViewController.MethodName

I am thinking if storing bViewController in variable of its own type and using that in place typecasting it will be any better.

what is the overhead associated with typecasting?

Comment: Why do you need to cast it at all?  Doesn't "MethodName" return an object of type `bViewController`?

Comment: This is starting point aViewController is of Type UIViewController. bViewController(my application view controller) in aViewContoller. I need to set some properties in bviewController.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have methods that are declared in the interface of aViewController and you want to message bViewController and have it implement those methods?

Comment: aViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, right? Can we see that header file and the method where you perform the typecast?

Comment: I am going to assume that whatever method you choose that becomes more readable and organized is far more important than worrying about performance. I assume the performance differences, if any, are far less than what it takes to load a view controller.

Comment: Why does this type of question come up so much?  What do you care about the performance of a cast?  Do you have numbers showing it is slow?  Write code for **humans**.  Make it correct, readable, and maintainable.  Then, gather actual performance numbers and address performance.

Comment: well I don't have any performance issue. I am curious about if one is better than other in terms of performance.

Comment: in appdelegate.h i have UIViewController *aViewController. and in appdelegate.m, I say aViewController = [[bViewController alloc] init]. and before bViewController is loaded i want to set some properties in bViewController in another method. this method loops through a large dictionary to set properties of bViewController. I was wondering which is the best practice, to store the bViewController outside the looping in a local variable or typecast it every time.

Comment: Casting costs essentially nothing, but is also unnecessary in this case.  Use the *real* class of the object for your pointer type and everything should work.  The only exception is some weird cases of protocols.

Comment: (Please show us the .h file lines that define your classes.  Or else learn the meaning of "subclass" and "superclass" and describe them in those terms.  Your descriptions so far have been unintelligible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be following standard naming conventions, hence the confusion apparent in the comments. This is my guess at what you doing:

You say you have:

```
UIViewController *aViewController;
```

Nothing wrong with that - the variable name starts with a lowercase letter. You then say you do:

```
aViewController = [[bViewController alloc] init];
```

Here `bViewController` is presumably a *class* and so by convention should start with an uppercase letter. You also don't say how this class is defined but presumably it is a subclass (correcting the case):

```
@interface BViewController : UIViewController
```

Now after the assignment above you wish to call a method defined in `BViewController` and so write:

((BViewController *)aViewController).propertyDefinedInBViewController

First calling a *method* is not (usually) done with the dot syntax, that is for *properties*. Second you need the extra parentheses otherwise you are casting the result of the property call and not `aViewController`.

Does that fit what you're doing?

If so, to your question - what is the cost of the typecast?

A typecast from one pointer type to another costs nothing, while a typecast between value types (integers, real numbers, etc.) may involve a run time conversion and carry a cost. Your case is the former so the cost is zero at runtime. However if you're making a lot of references I would recommend you use an intermediate variable of the correct type and cast just once, this tends to improve readability (development time cost). Also you should not cast to a subclass unless you've done a check you actually have an instance of the class, e.g.:

```
if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[BViewController class]])
{
   BViewController *myBViewController = (BViewController *)aViewController;
   ...
}
```

*or* you code guarantees you have an instance of the subclass and that is obvious or commented.

HTH and I've not completely guessed wrong what you're doing!